# Javascript - Concatenar file y string

Tags: javascript, string, blob

¿Es posible, en Javascript del lado del cliente, convertir un string en binario y agregarlo al final de un objeto File? El objetivo ee esto es transmitir el resultado via websocket (ya que no se pueden transmitir string y binarios al mismo tiempo por esta vía).

Comment: Depronto también podrias convertir el archivo a base64 que es texto y lo concatenas con el otro string de alguna manera

Comment: Realmente no es viable. Si el archivo es grande seria algo costoso convertirlo en base64. Y su tamaño aumentaria aun mas y seria mas pesado al enviarlo por websockets. Dos inconvenientes

Comment: Cuál sería el objetivo?? porque no enviarlos separados en envíos distintos?

Comment: He descubierto una forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es algo tan simple como esto:

```
new Blob ([ObjetoFile, 'Cadena'])
```

Incluso del lado del servidor es posible separar ambas partes, mostrar la cadena, y guardar el archivo en el disco duro.

Comment: Podrías marcar la pregunta como respondida para que le sea útil a otros.